# Firebase reporting too many Active Users

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, analytics, debugview

I'm creating an app which use Firebase and I haven't released it yet.
If I go to the Firebase console in the analytics tab I see 74 monthly active users. I suppose that is caused by installing multiple times on emulators during debug.
So I added

```
<meta-data
            android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated"
            android:value="${analytics_deactivated}" />
```

to the manifest and

```
buildTypes {
       debug {
           manifestPlaceholders = [analytics_deactivated: "true"]    
      }
}
```

to app.gradle and it seemed to work fine. 
Now I find out that firebase offer a good service which is DebugView that is make to help developers debug their app but it requires Firebase Analytics to be enabled.

Is there a way to use DebugView and don't count every installation as a new device?

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use different keys for debug and release, by creating 2 different projects. Or if you don't want to do that you might have to enable analytics logging only if it's release build